# Use Java Cipher equivalent in Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, cryptography

a i need help to decrypt values generated in Android Java App on Flutter.
I need a class who this but in Dart/Flutter:

public class TrippleDes {

```
//    public static String ALGO = "DESede/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
public static String ALGO = "DESede/ECB/PKCS7Padding";

public static String _encrypt(String message, String secretKey) throws Exception {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecreteKey(secretKey));

    byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] buf = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
    byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.encode(buf, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String base64EncryptedString = new String(base64Bytes);
    return base64EncryptedString;
}

public static String _decrypt(String encryptedText, String secretKey) throws Exception {

    byte[] message = Base64.decode(encryptedText.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

    Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecreteKey(secretKey));

    byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);

    return new String(plainText, "UTF-8");
}

public static SecretKey getSecreteKey(String secretKey) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(secretKey.getBytes("utf-8"));
    byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
    return key;
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far in coding? Please show us the code you are struggling with, thanks.

Comment: My problem is the SecretKey, i not understand how make this in dart

Comment: We are talking about decryption so simply use the same key as used for encryption.

Comment: Alrigth, but the key is an object, in flutter my key is a string, how to make the SecretKey object equivalent in Dart/Flutter

Comment: According to https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt it is a simple as in Java: final key = Key.fromUtf8('my 32 length key................');